# File API - reader.onload is never triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fileapi

I have multiple file inputs and want to generate preview of uploaded files for each input. I'm waiting for change on all of these inputs and then I trigger `new FileReader()`. Unfortunately the `onload` action is never triggered, what am I doing wrong?

```js
$("body").on("change", ".file", function(event){
  showPreview(event);
})

function showPreview(event){
 console.log("showPreview started");
  
 var file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log("file loaded: ", file);
  
        var reader = new FileReader();
        console.log("reader initiated: ", reader);
  
        reader.onload = function(event) {
     console.log("this never works : ", event);
          console.log(event.target.result);
        };
}
```

```css
label {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.preview {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 5px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <span class="preview"></span>
  <input type="file" class="file">
</label>

<label>
  <span class="preview"></span>
  <input type="file" class="file">
</label>

<label>
  <span class="preview"></span>
  <input type="file" class="file">
</label>

<label>
  <span class="preview"></span>
  <input type="file" class="file">
</label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x59gctL5/

Comment: @Teemu it doesn't, I can't see "this never works" anywhere in the logs.

Comment: Hmm. ... You don't do anything with the newly-created reader object.

Comment: Add `reader.readAsDataURL(file)` to trigger the onload

Comment: @Teemu yes, I would, but I can't as unload never happens.

Comment: Just creating an instance of FileReader doesn't trigger its onload event. As mplungjan said, you've to read a file ...

Comment: Any reason why my answer was not accepted? I commented first and answered first with a working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `readAsText()` within the event handler.

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload)

**Working code:**

```
function showPreview(event){
  // ... rest of your code

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    console.log("this never works : ", event);
    console.log(event.target.result);
  };

  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to trigger the event by reading the actual file

`reader.readAsDataURL(file);` or `reader.readAsText(file);`

then you can insert the image:

```
$span.html('<img src="' + event.target.result + '" />')
```

or text:

```
$span.html(event.target.result)
```

```js
$("body").on("change", ".file", function(event) {
  showPreview(event);
})

function showPreview(event) {
  console.log("showPreview started");
  var $span = $(event.target).prev();
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  console.log("file loaded: ", file);

  var reader = new FileReader();
  console.log("reader initiated: ", reader);

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.result);
    $span.html('<img src="' + event.target.result + '" />')

  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```css
label {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.preview {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 5px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <span class="preview"></span>
  <input type="file" class="file">
</label>

<label>
  <span class="preview"></span>
  <input type="file" class="file">
</label>

<label>
  <span class="preview"></span>
  <input type="file" class="file">
</label>

<label>
  <span class="preview"></span>
  <input type="file" class="file">
</label>
```